# is it possible to build complex applications with gadgets

Tags: soa, opensocial, google-gadget

It seems that [gadgets](http://opensocial.org/) are focused on constructing small pieces of user interface functionality.

Is it possible to build complex applications where the UI is built only with gadgets?  If so, what are the pitfalls of this approach?  Are there any online examples of complex gadget based UI's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short yes.

When it boils down to it gadgets use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript so they are essentially web applications and can do anything any other web application can do (and more in the OpenSocial case).  Your entire app can be composed of a single gadget or multiple.  If there are multiple gadgets they can even communicate between each other.  You may want to compose an app from multiple gadget if the information is coming from disperse systems and you want to build reusable components.  The one thing to be careful of in these cases is load time of everything on the page because each gadget is its own iframe.